# Deploying Angular aplication

Tags: angular, angular8

this is the first time I'm deploying an Angular application. It is properly working at localhost, consuming data from a server (right now it is cross origin enabled), so there should be no problem with it. I built a production version, as suggested in the docs.

> ng build --prod

Then, I moved the prod folder into the same server where the backend scripts are running. I also copied the node_modules to that folder. I visited the URL and the HTML is loading, but just that. There is no error thrown. No style. No angular app working.

How can I know which error I'm having?

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main concept of how it works is:

1. You build files locally with `ng build --prod`. Angular CLI creates `dist` folder with compiled js files, assets, index.html, and styles.
2. You copy this folder (or its content) to the web server. No need to copy `node_modules` folder because everything is compiled into scripts inside `dist` folder
3. Your web server should be configured the following way:

   - to get all static files(scripts, styles, assets) from the web server folder. For example `https://<yourdomain>.com/main.js` - should return `main.js`
   - handle requests to the API (if API and frontend are on the same domain)
   - redirect other requests to the `index.html` file. Imagine the URL `https://<yourdomain>.com/about`. `about` - we guess it is a route of your Angular application. Then your server returns `index.html` to the browser. The browser fetches scripts and styles (p.1) and scripts launch an Angular app. The angular app understands that it should show `about` route.